# How do I keep the window centered on a particular line number while switching files in vim?

Tags: vim, gvim

I need to quickly compare different versions of a file and need to constantly change to a new file. Is it possible to fix the cursor on a particular line number while I cycle through different files?

The context for this is while using Fugitive.vim's Glog command, I need to change from one version of a file to the next and compare the same location.

EDIT: This also needs to work within the quicklist when switching between files using :cnext and :cprev

Cheers,
Durand

Comment: Why don't you use diff?

Comment: I do occasionally use diffthis but I need to switch between files quickly and constantly typing diffthis in both splits is a bit annoying... Unless I am doing it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will move the cursor to line 50 for each file you view and also center that line in the display.

```
:au BufRead * silent! 50 | normal zz
```

**Post-Acceptance Update:**

The above works when jumping within a list of files with `:n` and `:N`, but does not work when traversing the quickfix list with `:cn` and `:cp`. Following a discussion in the comments, the solution that actually worked was to use mappings such as these.

```
:map <C-N> :cn<CR>50Gzz
:map <C-P> :cp<CR>50Gzz
```

Comment: Hmm. It doesn't seem to do anything...

EDIT: Okay, so it works if I use :e to open a file but not if I am switching between files within the quicklist...

Comment: The quickfix list usually (always?) contains line numbers as well as file names, so without knowing more, I'd guess that the line numbers in the quickfix list are trumping the one in the autocommand. I tested my answer with `:n` and `:N`. I tried replacing `BufRead` with `BufEnter`, but that didn't help in my brief experimentation with a quickfix list. Depending on how you travers the quickfix list, you might try this mapping: `:map <C-N> :cn<CR>50Gzz`.

Comment: Aha, thanks! I didn't know about the 50Gzz shortcut :)

Comment: Thanks for updating the answer. That's basically what I ended up using though in the future, I may write a little script to select the current line rather than line 50, for example.